# Corrected parameters (dimensional analysis) interpretation

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Currently, I am going through 'Gas Turbine Parameter Corrections' by Volponi.

There is a statement:

> Blockquote
> For any gas path parameter $X$, the equivalent corrected parameter will be denoted by $X_{c}$ throughout this discussion. In general, a change in the engine inlet conditions $T_{2}$ (inlet total temperature) and $P_{2}$ (inlet total pressure) will be accompanied by an attendant change in any downstream gas path parameter $X$. A corrected parameter $X_{c}$ would be constant regardless of the change in inlet condition and represents the value the parameter $X$ would have at some fixed reference inlet condition. This reference condition can be whatever you like, however, it is common practice to select the International Standard Atmosphere (ISA) standard day conditions.

I must admit I can't grasp the concept. Let's focus on temperature:

$T_{c} = \frac{T}{\theta}$, where $\theta = \frac{T_{2}}{T_{ISA}}$

$T_{2}$ is a temperature at the engine inlet.

$T_{ISA}$ is a standard day temperature according to ISA standard: 288.15K

So let's assume we measured temperature at the turbine exit: $T_{5} = 900 ~K$, for engine inlet temperature $T_{2} = 310 ~ K$.

So if I would calculate corrected turbine exit temperature: $T_{5, c} = \frac{900}{\frac{310}{288.15}} = 828 ~ K$, what would that mean? How to understand it?

Many thanks for your help,
Luk

Comment: You should try to at least provide some context on your question. There's not much that leads to a specific problem apart from some formulas and symbols corresponding to some (rather arbitrary) physical quantities. As is, your question is very vague and I strongly suggest you try to describe the problem a bit better.

Comment: Volponi is defining a gas turbine performance based on standard conditions.  This information is useful when comparing two or more turbines, or when evaluating performance characteristics over time (i.e., it is "an apples to apples" comparison)

Comment: @DavidWhite Could you be more specific. Any example? Your answer is too general for me to understand the concept.

Comment: @Łukasz, if you are operating a gas turbine under varying conditions for some length of time, and you want to know if it is performing approximately as well as it did when new, you need to convert all your measurements to something that is standard such that you can make a comparison over various time intervals.

Comment: @DavidWhite, it makes more sense now, but still struggle a bit. So, using the equation I wrote above I can bring all measurements to the standard day, to compare apple to apple. But something needs to be held constant. According to Volponi 'we willl assume that local Mach numbers along the gas path have remain fixed'.  And now the question is: how this assumption is done in practice?

Comment: @Łukasz, I'm not experienced with gas turbines.  However, I do know what the author was trying to convey.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I will be grateful for any hint.